# WPF TextBox doesn't take input in popup

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, telerik, popup

I have a winform application. Inside the main form I host a RadDocking control (from telerik) which is WPF. When I click on a pane that is hidden it opens the pane as a popup. Inside there is a textbox. If I type in the textbox it takes the input. but if I give focus back to the mainform and then try to type again it won't take any input. I saw that there is a solution here: [WPF TextBox doesn't take input, space and backspace works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163556/wpf-textbox-doesnt-take-input-space-and-backspace-works) and the solution was to write

```
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window);
```

But unfortunately I just can't get the window. This is what I tried:

```
 private Window FindWindowParent(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {

        var window = dependencyObject as Window;

        if (window != null || dependencyObject == null)
        {
            return window;
        }

        if (dependencyObject.GetType().Name.Equals("PopupRoot"))
        {
            return FindWindowParent(LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject));
        }

        return FindWindowParent(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject));
    }
```

When I get to the popuproot - it has no visual parent so I switched to the LogicalTreeHelper and I get the Popup itself but it has no window as a parent (because it is hosted inside the winforms).
So I'm stuck, I can't get the window of the popup to fix the problem.

I also tried:

```
var window = Window.GetWindow(dependencyObject);
```

Didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found solution?